# AWS C++ SDK unresolved external "W" version of method

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, vcpkg, aws-sdk-cpp

I'm using the AWS C++ SDK from a Visual Studio project. The SDK was installed using vcpkg. Building the project gives the following linker error:

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class Aws::Utils::Outcome<class Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectResult,class Aws::S3::S3Error> __thiscall Aws::S3::S3Client::GetObjectW(class Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest const &)const " (?GetObjectW@S3Client@S3@Aws@@UBE?AV?$Outcome@VGetObjectResult@Model@S3@Aws@@VS3Error@34@@Utils@3@ABVGetObjectRequest@Model@23@@Z)

The method used in the code is `Aws::S3::S3Client::GetObject`. This seems to be in the library installed by vcpkg, but the linker is looking for `GetObjectW`.

Why does it seem to be looking for a wide character version, and how do I correct this?

Comment: `GetObject` should be an Macro that call `GetObjectW` if you are in UNICODE mode and `GetObjectA` if you are in ASCII mode In _Windows.h_: [Solution](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/625)

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166869/awssdkcpp-s3client-getobject).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) Or at least are you sure you link correctly?

Comment: `#undef GetObject` to undefine the macro.

Comment: Yes, it was the GetObject macro. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conflict with a Windows macro for an identically named Windows function, and has nothing to do with the AWS SDK. Undefining the macro before including the AWS headers solves this issue:

```
#undef GetObject
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
...
```